# JavaScript opens the window in the background instead of foreground in Chrome and Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the below JavaScript function to open a new window when a user clicks on a link.

```
function popWinSimple(url,features) {
    win = window.open(url,'',features);
    win.focus();
}
```

This function opens the window in the foreground  on Firefox but does not do the same on Safari and Chrome.

What may be the cause of this difference in behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

As I know you cant change this behaviour, as this is handled by user setting in every browser.

Answer (score 1):

Using Safari and Chrome in nearly-stock configurations on OSX Lion, I am loading the following page.  The behaviour I am observing is that the tab loads in the front for case 1 and 2, and case 3 flashes to the front and then focus returns to the calling tab.  I do not think there is any stronger or more reliable method than javascript's focus() and blur() calls for this case.

```
<html>
    <body>
        <a href="." onclick="javascript:var w = window.open('foo.html'); return false;">click normal</a>
        <br />
        <a href="." onclick="javascript:var w = window.open('foo.html'); w.focus(); return false;">click and focus</a>
        <br />
        <a href="." onclick="javascript:var w = window.open('foo.html'); w.blur(); window.focus(); return false;">click and unfocus</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I've also run into this Chrome-specific problem whenever the window.open call is made from within an iframe. I found a workaround for the issue that makes the popup open in the foreground even in Chrome (Firefox and Safari don't have this issue):

1. Pass the event parameter into your onclick handler:

   ```
   <button onclick="popWinSimple(event, 'url', 'features')">Popup window</button>
   ```
2. Call preventDefault on the event:

   ```
   function popWinSimple(event, url, features) {
     event.preventDefault();
     win = window.open(url, '', features);
     win.focus();
   }
   ```

Note: I don't think you need to call win.focus() since by default the new popup will take focus. Also, in Chrome win.focus() is disabled for security reasons.